# Show / hide dataLabels on legend click

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I am working on Stacked Column Chart in Highcharts. I have a requirement that on every click of a legend the dataLabels on that series should be shown/hidden but the series/stack should not be hidden. So I only want to hide/show dataLabels.

I tried this and got the series to stop hiding by using this:

```
events: {
    legendItemClick: function () {
        return false; // <== returning false will cancel the default action
    }
}
```

But I am not able to show dataLabels on click of a legend.

Here is the [Fiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/vy1062qr/).

Comment: return true works fine in your fiddle

Comment: Why you asked the same question again? you could edit the same question

Comment: @NitinDhomse the chart is same but both have different requirements

Comment: `return true;` hides the stack. I want stack to be always visible and only hide/ show the datalabels

Comment: that's fine, still you could mention the two different scenario in the single question.

Comment: Did separate to avoid confusion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
legendItemClick: function (x) {
                    x.preventDefault()
                  var opt = x.target.chart.options.plotOptions.series;
    opt.dataLabels.enabled = !opt.dataLabels.enabled;
    x.target.chart.series[x.target.index].update(opt);
                  //x.target.chart.options.plotOptions.series.dataLabels.enabled=false
                   // <== returning false will cancel the default action
                    }
```

Comment: check if this is what you want

Comment: Thank you @undefined_variable

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @undefined_variable for your answer.

I have found one more way to do it using `this`.

```
legendItemClick: function () {
    var enabled = !this.options.dataLabels.enabled;
    this.update({
        dataLabels:{
            enabled: enabled
        }
    });
    return false; 
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nh48c2yp/)